# Nonmeasurable functions and the axiom of choice

Tags: measure-theory

Hi everyone: We know that to construct a nonmeasurable function one must to use the axiom of choice. Can we conclude that to avoid all nonmeasurable functions it suffices to reject the axiom of choice?!!!!

Comment: I read somewhere that if you reject the existence of large cardinal, it's possible to construct nonmeasurable set without axiom of choice.

Comment: Are you asking if the existence of a nonmeasurable set implies the axiom of choice ?

Comment: There are weaker set theoretic axioms than choice which allow for the existence of Lebesgue nonmeasurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Benedetto and Czaja discuss this point in Integration and Modern Analysis.

Comment: For instance, the ultrafilter lemma is enough and it is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify my question: According to Gerald Folland in his "Modern Analysis", Solovay has proved that it is impossible to prove the existence of Lebesgue nonmeasurable sets without using the axiom of choice (pg 41). My point is here: Since some mathematicians do not accept the axiom of choice, so for them all sets are Lebesgue measurable! Is that correct?!!!

Comment: Folland writes that the result of Solovay **in effect** shows that it is not possible to show the existence of nonmeasurable sets w.o. using choice. Also note the paranthesis after that statement where he clarifies that a correct formulation of that statement is outside the scope of the book. Also note that not being able to show that there are no nonmeasurable sets is **not** the same as being able to show that all sets are measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you do not need Axiom of Choice in order to prove existence of non-measurable subsets of ${\mathbb R}$, it suffices to have the Hahn-Banach extension theorem, which is strictly weaker than axiom of choice (plus Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms). Thus, merely rejecting Axiom of Choice is not enough. I do not know what is your mathematical background, but if you use functional analysis (or maybe PDEs), my suggestion is to keep the H-B theorem even at the price of existence of nonmeasurable sets.